# Backup of a running Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, server, backup, virtualization

I work as administrator of a DPC (making backups to migrate the whole system), and I inherited a server full of different operating systems (different VM's running on Windows Server), in turn with different software for the same tasks. Following this, I constantly encounter all kinds of software, with which sometimes I have never worked.

One of the VMs uses ISPConfig, and it works as a proxy for more than 15 websites. I need to backup this VM but the method I'm using to backup the rest of the VM for migration reports an error because this VM is actually a Snapshot of the original. The VM does not start well because of a configuration failure and we have decided not to restart it again. Because of that and because I do not know very well which files are related to ISPConfig:

How could I make a copy of all the data found in the VM (Ubuntu server 12.04.1), except for the /dev, /mnt,... directories, so that I can restore them in a test VM and check if it serves as a backup of the current VM in the server?

I would like to do this without installing any package, or at least without installing any that could force me to restart the VM, as I have already mentioned, restarting it before saving critical information is not an option.

I know that this question may have been asked before, but the proposed solutions that I have seen involve the installation of software or the shutdown of the system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand it, to run ISPConfig, you also need Apache, PHP, MySQL, PureFTPD, BIND, Postfix, Dovecot, and probably a few more packages. The settings for these packages will all be in `/etc` and the data in `/var`, so that would be where your most critical data is. To replicate the current server you need to find out exactly which packages are running, and then we can tell you what to backup.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find it out, and then i will post it here. Thanks for de advide @Jos .